# I invited my friend but I realised that I forgot/had forgotten to give him the address

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

> I invited my friend, but later l realised that l ....... to give him
>   the address.

- A: forgot
- B: had forgotten

I think that B is true but it's written in the book that A is the correct one. 
Is that because the first action is the verb "give" not the verb "forget"? but I think that the verb to give didn't actually happen.
Can someone please explain why A is the correct answer?

Comment: "but it's written in the book that A is the correct one". Which book would that be?

Comment: Well, it's hard to explain. I am a secondary school student. We have our school English book but we don't use it. We use alternative books that should be written by specialists but they sometimes make mistakes

Comment: Though I forgot is probably the answer, I think the reason is probably the past perfect "had forgotten" should be used in "comparison" with the another even time, which, in this case, you invited your friend. The time frame is same, you invited = simple past, and forgot = simple past. There is no reason you need to use the past perfect to differentiate the time recognition.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the act of inviting and the act of giving (or in this case, forgetting to give) the address would've happened *at the same time*, meaning you'd use the same verb tense.

Usually "had + past participle" is used when that action took place *before* the simple past verb action. As in:

*I invited my friend, and before that I had eaten dinner.*

But it doesn't quite make sense to have forgotten to give your friend the address *before* doing the inviting. Clearly you forgot to give the address *at the same time you're doing the inviting*. And, evidently, you continued to forget to give the address for every moment afterward.

So in a very wordy way, I think the idea is:

*I invited my friend, but later I realised that, while I was in the process of inviting him, I forgot to give him the address.*

However, if I didn't know "A" was the right answer, I would've put "B" myself. I think this is the reason for why "A" is right, though. You can't forget the address *exclusively before* doing the inviting. You forgot possibly before (depends on if the invite was premeditated or impromptu), certainly during the inviting, and definitely after the inviting.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent answer on English Language Usage ["Forgot" vs "Have forgotten"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420245/forgot-vs-have-forgotten). Their conclusion coincides with mine (by sheer dumb luck, I think) that either is acceptable. Or as they put it "*from a casual conversational point of view the two are largely used interchangeably*".

The interesting thing about their answer is their assessment of the tense in each example sentence.

BTW, disregard the "Marked as Duplicate" status of that question. I think it was a wrong decision; the other question deals with a very different issue.

Comment: ahm...the OP's question is "had forgotten". That's so different from "have forgotten".